# I am not able to push my docker Image on Elastic container registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I created an ecr
I have authenticated with aws and I am able to do docke login successfully but still getting not authorised while pushing my image
I also tried sudo but I am using windows

I am putting the error image for reference
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0kQj.png)

Answer (score 0):

I made a script recently, see if it helps

```
import os


def build(account_id, image_name, repository_name, docker_file):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    account_id: AWS account ID
    image_name: Docker image to be built and assigned a name
    repository_name: AWS ECR repository name
    docker_file: The docker file to use
    """
    print("starting docker build...")
    os.system(
        'docker build --pull --rm -f "'
        + docker_file
        + '" -t '
        + image_name
        + ':latest "."'
    )
    print("done.")

    print("logging in aws ecr...")
    os.system(
        "aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin "
        + account_id
        + ".dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    )
    print("done.")

    print("tagging...")
    os.system(
        "docker tag "
        + image_name
        + ":latest "
        + account_id
        + ".dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
        + repository_name
    )
    print("done.")

    print("pushing to ecr...")
    os.system(
        "docker push "
        + account_id
        + ".dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
        + repository_name
    )
    print("done.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    docker_file_name = ""
    aws_account_id = ""
    docker_image_name = ""
    ecr_repository_name = ""
    build(aws_account_id, docker_image_name, ecr_repository_name, docker_file_name)
```